# Prove the limit below using definition

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove the limit using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definition

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} xy = 1$$

Thanks!

Comment: *Hint:* $xy-1 = x(y-1) + (x-1)$.

Comment: Sorry, then? I just don't know how to proceed it.

Comment: Now $|xy-1| = |x(y-1)| + |x-1| < \varepsilon$, if $|x-1| < \delta$ and $|y-1| < \delta$, where $\delta = \min\{\varepsilon/3, 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $xy-1 = x(y-1) + (x-1)$.

> For any $\varepsilon > 0$ let $\delta := \min\left\{\dfrac{\varepsilon}{3}, 1\right\}$. Then $|xy-1| \le |x|\cdot|y-1| + |x-1| < \varepsilon$, whenever $|x-1| < \delta$ and $|y-1| < \delta$.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the upvote.

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$